# C++ with ASM x86 Encryption/Decryption Program

Tags: c++, encryption, assembly, x86

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I decrypt this encryption routine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677101/how-can-i-decrypt-this-encryption-routine)

I have been on this program for a week now and I am so confused. I tried everything and anything
but I didn't manage to make it work. I would really appreciate it if you could give me some help with my program.
thank you.

I have the following code and I need to write the Decryption routine for it.

```
OChars = Original char -> is the word which the user types in.           
EKey = The Encryption Key (one letter)              
Length = The length of characters that the user needs to put             
EChars = Stores the Encrypted characters in so the decryption routine can use it to decrypt it.

    void encrypt_chars (int length, char EKey){
char temp_char;                 // original/encrypted char temporary store

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    temp_char = OChars [i];     // get next char from original string
    __asm {                     // call the encrypt subroutine
        push   eax              // save register values on stack to be safe
        push   ecx
        movsx  ecx,temp_char    // enregister the source character
        movsx  eax,EKey         // and encryption key.
        call   encryptB         // calls the encryption subroutingencrypt the character
        mov    temp_char,al     // only need lower byte of EAX to return encrypted char
        pop    ecx              // restore original register values from stack
        pop    eax
    }
    EChars [i] = temp_char;     // Store encrypted char in the encrypted chars array
   }
     return;

encryption routine ASM          

     __asm {

encryptB: push edx          //saves register value edx on stack
          push ecx          //saves register value ecx on stack
          not  eax          //
          add  eax,0x04     //add 4 to eax register
          mov  edx,eax      //move eax to edx
          pop  eax          //brings eax back to
          xor  eax,edx      //clear values to zero
          pop  edx          //bring edx back 
          rol  al,3         //three times.
          sub  al,0x02      //subtracts 2 from al
          ret 
}               
Here ends the encryption part            
The decryption routine will start as follows             

void decrypt_chars (int length, char EKey){
  char temp_char;                       

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    temp_char = EChars [i];         
    __asm {                         


     }

      DChars [i] = temp_char;           
}
 return;

decryption routine ASM

__asm {


      }
```

Comment: This is how the tutor gave it to us =/ thank you for ur quick reply

Comment: This is prime example of overcommented code. Everybody who knows assembly (people who don't won't help you out much anyway) can read those instructions, so they don't need the comments. What they, however, could make use of is explaining what value the registers are supposed to contain at which point. Which is not mentioned.

Comment: First figure out the algorithm of the encryption routine. Write it out on paper. Then figure out the algorithm to reverse it. Then implement that algorithm.

Comment: @JanHudec thank you and sorry for all the comments i wanted to be clear =/ the registers save the characters that the user puts. and the EKey which is a letter.(any letter). is this what you mean? I am new to this so I am sorry if I am not clear

Comment: @alex: Actually, the comments are key to this. Replace them with good comments and you'll be much closer to the solution.

Comment: @Eelke i have been writing this algorithm to find how i can to the opposite of it. but nothing. I am really trying for a whole week now. thank you eelke

Comment: @JanHudec I tried really hard to make it on paper and with comments. but this is really hard for me. i am so confused

Comment: "I am so confused" is not really going to fly. Do you actually understand the assembler instructions? If not, consult e.g. an Intel reference book first. Then, find out what the encryption really does.

Comment: @alex -I can imagine such a homework only in reverse engineering course. Any comments from tutor on why would you need it in your life?

Comment: @FrederikSlijkerman i understand the assembler instructions but i am new  and might getting something wrong for sure. and because i have to finish this until tomorrow is the reason I have ask you guys for any help. thank you

Comment: @SChepurin actually its not reverse engineering :) and i might need this in future who knows.. but in some way i agree with you

Comment: I clearly remember already answering this question. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677101/how-can-i-decrypt-this-encryption-routine

Comment: while i was searching for help in the net.. i found your post but i am not sure if i need to change anytihng from the void decrypt(asm part) if anyone could answer this please? i mean does it needs to stay the same as the void encrypt?  thanks

Comment: @alex it's not supposed to stay the same, see the linked question for details

Comment: @harold i mean the ASM inside void encrypt_chars should be the same for void decrypt_char ?

Comment: @alex oh that part, well it depends, not if you intend to use my decryption code directly (it doesn't pop anything, it expects arguments in registers).

Comment: i have written the void decrypt part as you can see in the code above.. any ideas of what i need to put in the asm ?

Comment: @alex on second thought I think it can be the same. Although, obviously, it shouldn't call "encryptB" but whatever you decided to call the decryption code (decryptB?)

Comment: @harold yes i have called it different name..and left it the same! Changed the calling asm so it can decrypt the chars.. but i dont get the output i want

Comment: Oh yes, I remember why. In the other question, the asker didn't tell me which was the key and which was the input, so I got it wrong. Hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it XOR's with the `f(Key)` where `f` is some function, all computations have to be undone *except* the ones that make up `f` - they have to be done normally.

So, something like this: (not tested)

```
; eax = EKey, cl = char
decryptB:
  add ecx, 2   // undo sub 2
  ror cl, 3    // undo rol
  not eax      // actually do not
  add eax, 4   // actually do add 4
  xor eax, ecx // undo xor
  ret
```

Comment: why should i add 4 to eax again? in the encrypt it also adds 4 ? shouldn't i have sub 4?

Comment: @alex no that's part of `f`, or in other words, it transforms the key. The transformed key should be the same as the transformed key in the encryption, because it's being `xor`ed with the data. So the transformation has to be the same, too.

Comment: Honestly it seems like they made this confusing on purpose. I can't think of any good reason to transform the key like this at all, but they do it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Try encrypting character 'E' with key 'K' and see what the routine is doing each step. Then try to right the undo of each operation next to them. Reverse the order of undo instructions set to get the 'undo' of the encryption routine.

Comment: Step through it with the debugger indeed.

Comment: i tried to count how many places in ascii take the character back or forward. but this code is encrypting for good my characters. if this is what you mean. thank you btw

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest starting with replacing those useless comments that just expand the instruction mnemonics with description what value is manipulated in each step. Something like:

```
    push   eax              // avoid clobbering registers; just preamble
    push   ecx
    movsx  ecx,temp_char    // ecx = byte_to_encrypt
    movsx  eax,EKey         // eax = key
    ...
    push ecx                // Stack[0] = byte_to_encrypt
    ...
    pop eax                 // eax = byte_to_encrypt now...
```

and so on. Now when you have that, it should be easy to distil a pseudo-code and eventually mathematical formula for the operation. That should be easy to reverse and than you just code it back (in assembly, if that's required), without all the pointless shuffling of values between registers.

Comment: thank you Jan I have allready try to put some meaningful comments and really tried to make it on paper.  Do i need to change anything on the asm in void? or just change the asm below? thank you